# Jquery hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I a building a simple FAQ page on my site.  I'd like the question only to be visible, and once the user clicks on the question it should then show the answer.  for some reason my code isn't working. Please review my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

**html**

```
<div class="copy" id="about1">
        <h1>The Mission</h1>
        <p>
            content content content

            content content content

            content content content

        </p>

  <h1>The Game</h1>
        <p>
            content content content

            content content content

            content content content

        </p>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.copy h1').onclick(function(){
          $('.copy p').hide();
        $('this').next('p').show();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.copy p{
  display=none;
}
```

Comment: try $(this) instead of $('this')

Comment: In your CSS it should be `display: none;` **not** `display=none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues. First, in your JS, you've made two mistakes -- `onclick()` should be `click()`, and you've wrapped `this` in single-quotes. It should read:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.copy h1').click(function(){
      $('.copy p').hide();
      $(this).next('p').show();
    });
});
```

Second, in your CSS, the separator between keys and values should be a colon:

```
.copy p {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some errors in your code.
You will find a correction here: http://jsfiddle.net/fQYLm//

Error 1 : `display:none` and not `display = none`

Error 2 : `$('.copy h1').live('click',function() {` and not `.onclick`

Error 3 : `$(this).next('p').show();` and not `$('this')`

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one : it'll toggle the show hide effect for answer with click on question

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.copy h1').toggle(function(){
       $(this).next('p').show();
   },function(){
       $(this).next('p').hide();
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.copy h1').bind('click', function(){
        $('.copy p').hide();
        $(this).next('p').show();

    });
});
```

First of all, bind the 'click' event and $('this') is not the same as $(this).

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with what you've pasted. First up, you've got bad CSS syntax. Try:

```
.copy p { display: none;}
```

(that is, use a `:`, not an `=`).

Secondly, in your javascript, you want to use `.click()` rather than `.onclick()`; and `$(this)` rather than `$('this')`. Also, jQuery has a short-form of `$(document).ready()`. Your Javascript should look like:

```
$(function() {
 $('.copy h1').click(function(){
            $('.copy p').hide();
      $(this).next('p').show(); 
 });
});
```